# While Inserting records in SQLite returns -1

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my `SimpleDBAdapter Class` that encapsulates all the complexities of accessing the database and the inner class `SimpleDBHelper` takes care of CRUD operations,now the Problem that I am facing here is that when I deploy the code, the tables were getting created, but I am unable to insert the values in to the table, the `id` is returning `-1` that depicts that there is an error,while inserting the values.

```
id = db.insert(TABLE_SIMPLETABLE_CLIENT1,null,contentvalues);
```

SimpleDBAdapter.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams;

public class SimpleDBAdapter {
    // Define all the constants that are to used in the Program
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SimpleDB.db";
    private static final String TABLE_SIMPLETABLE_CLIENT1 = "SimpleTable1";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String KEY_EMPLOYEE_ID = "Employee_id";
    private static final String KEY_EMPLOYEE_NAME = "Name";
    private static final String KEY_EMPLOYEE_DESIGNATION = "Designation";
    private static final String KEY_EMPLOYEE_MARITUALSTATUS = "Maritual Status";
    private static final String KEY_EMPLOYEE_DOJ = "Date of Joining";

    private static final String TAG = "SimpleDBAdapter";

    String CREATE_TABLE_SIMPLETABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + TABLE_SIMPLETABLE_CLIENT1
        + " (Employee_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + "  Employee_Name VARCHAR(20)," + "  JoinedDateTime DATETIME,"
        + "  Designation VARCHAR(20),"
        + "  Maritual_Status BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'FALSE');";

    private final Context ctx;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private SimpleDBHelper simpledbhelper;

    public SimpleDBAdapter(Context context) {
    Log.i(TAG,"SimpleDBAdapter Constructor");
     ctx = context;
     simpledbhelper = new SimpleDBHelper(ctx);
    }

      class SimpleDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static final String TAG = "SimpleDBHelper";
        public SimpleDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.i(TAG,"Calling.. super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION)");
        }   

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Creating Table named CREATE_TABLE_SIMPLETABLE");
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SIMPLETABLE);
               }



        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgarding from" + oldversion + "to" + newversion
                    + "could remove all the old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_SIMPLETABLE_CLIENT1");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    //Opens the DB
    public void open() throws SQLException {
        Log.i(TAG,"Open() Called...");
        db = simpledbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        simpledbhelper.onCreate(db);

    }

    //closes the DB
    public void close() {
        Log.i(TAG,"Close() Called...");
        simpledbhelper.close();
    }

    //inserting the values in to Table
    public long insertEntry(String Name,String Designation,Boolean MaritualStatus,String date){
        Log.i(TAG,"Insert Entry ()");
        long id = 0;
        try{
        ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
        contentvalues.put(KEY_EMPLOYEE_NAME, Name);
        contentvalues.put(KEY_EMPLOYEE_DOJ,date);
        contentvalues.put(KEY_EMPLOYEE_DESIGNATION, Designation);
        contentvalues.put(KEY_EMPLOYEE_MARITUALSTATUS, MaritualStatus);
        id = db.insert(TABLE_SIMPLETABLE_CLIENT1,null,contentvalues);
        }
        catch(Exception err){
            Log.i(TAG,"Error Encountered...");
            Log.e(TAG,String.valueOf(err).toString());
        }
        return id;
    }

}
```

In the `MainClass` file (DBHandler.java), i am creating instance of the code and calling the insert method of this class as follows,

DBHandler.java

import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class SimpleDBApplication extends Activity {
        private static final String TAG = "SimpleDBApplication";
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            SimpleDBAdapter DBAdapter = new SimpleDBAdapter(this);
            Log.i(TAG,"Called SimpleDBAdapter");
            //call to open the DB
            DBAdapter.open();
            long id;
          //  add an entry
          id = DBAdapter.insertEntry("Vinayaka","CEO",false,"17-7-2010");
          Log.w(TAG,"Tuple Inserted");
          Log.w(TAG," The Value of ID :" +String.valueOf(id).toString());

        //call to close the DB
          DBAdapter.close();


        }
    }

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see so far, your ContentValues keys are not the same as the column names, which should be as I recall.

So your constants would have to become;

```
private static final String KEY_EMPLOYEE_ID = "Employee_ID";
private static final String KEY_EMPLOYEE_NAME = "Employee_Name";
private static final String KEY_EMPLOYEE_DESIGNATION = "Designation";
private static final String KEY_EMPLOYEE_MARITUALSTATUS = "Maritual_Status";
private static final String KEY_EMPLOYEE_DOJ = "JoinedDateTime";
```

if that doesn't solve your problem, try to post the stacktrace, so that we have more details to help you.

Comment: Indeed, if nothing else fails, that should.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the specific reason if instead of `insert()` you use `insertOrThrow()` and catch the exception, then the error message should help you figure out the reason quickly.

Comment: Hi,Guys ,Thanks a lot for helping me to find the error, finally insertOrthrow() get me the error, this is the error that i got,

08-20 17:07:18.281: ERROR/SimpleDBAdapter(201): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
near "Status": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO SimpleTable1(Name, Maritual Status, Designation, Date of Joining) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);

Any knowledge about this error guys?